# How does one know what IDE was used for an open-source Java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, openfire

I'm new to Java and Eclipse (C# developer here). I have a requirement to take an open-source Java application (OpenFire) and modify it to suit our needs.

I downloaded Eclipse Juno, I downloaded OpenFire. But something tells me that OpenFire was written using another IDE because when I try to open it in Eclipse, it complains about the  element missing in the build.xml file (I used the "Open from an existing Ant BuildFile" option, which OpenFire has).

What can be the best way to approach this type of situation knowing that open-source can be written using so many tools out there? The goal is not to have to change much of the files just to get it into an IDE.

Any help or direction would help.

Comment: Who says the application was built using an IDE at all? Or if it was, whether only one was used?  Not everyone uses an IDE, and generally speaking, it's not necessary for a project to standardize on any particular one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE does not make a difference to the project unless there are IDE-specific artifacts like `.classpath` in the project tree. The `build.xml` file format is set by Ant, not by any one IDE, so it is extremely unlikely that the IDE is the source of your difficulty.

However, IDE-specific files have no place in the source repository.

Rather than chase down a red herring, look at the error in the `build.xml` and fix that.

Also, to diagnose if your IDE is mismanaging Ant, use `ant` from the command line to build your project. You should never depend on the IDE to build your project for you, and never use the IDE to build the project for someone else to use. Always use standard build tools like Ant or Maven or Gradle, and always run them from command line or script to get "official" builds.

If you can run your build that way, you are guaranteed independence of IDE irregularities.

Comment: You're right. When I build the OpenFire project using commant-line Ant, I get no errors, and build successfully. But the problem I'm having is loading the files in Eclipse. As explained in my question, when I use the "Open from an existing Ant BuildFile" option, it refuses to load because the build.xml is missing a javac Task. Should I be loading the project differently in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it helped answer my question but I'm disappointed in the fact that I have to run ant from the command line to build my project. Defeats the purpose of an IDE (the "I" stands for integrated). If we need to build that way, then why use an IDE?

Comment: If you know what the build.xml is missing, why not add that piece and see what happens? Also, as an experiment, use your IDE to create a new Ant-based project (not from an existing `build.xml`) so that the IDE creates the `build.xml` for you. Perhaps studying what the IDE creates can help you figure out what it expects​.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the best way to approach this type of situation knowing that open-source can be written using so many tools out there?

This problem has been already solved by IDE and platform independent build tools which are tightly integrated with most of the popular IDEs

Maven, Gradle are examples of such tools

These build tools also has standard configuration and directory structure which is understandable by popular IDEs